# How to further process a Nokogiri::XML::Element?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I've written a short script in Ruby using Nokogiri to extract some data from a web page. The script works fine, but it is currently returning several nested tags as a single Nokogiri::XML::Element.

The script is as follows:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

#some dummy content that mimics the structure of the web page
dummy_content = '<div id="div_saadi"><div><div style="padding:10px 0"><span class="t4">content</span>content outside of the span<span class="t2">morecontent</span>morecontent outside of the span</div></div></div>'
page = Nokogiri::HTML(dummy_content)

#grab the second div inside of the div entitled div_saadi
result = page.css('div#div_saadi div')[1]

puts result
puts result.class
```

output is as follows:

```
<div style="padding:10px 0">
<span class="t4">content</span>content outside of the span<span class="t2">morecontent</span>morecontent outside of the span
</div>
Nokogiri::XML::Element
```

What I'd like to do is to produce the following output (using something like .each):

```
content
content outside of the span
morecontent
morecontent outside of the span
```

Comment: You need to supply a more comprehensive example of the HTML _IN_ your question. Don't point us at a link, as links rot and die.

Comment: `result` is going to be a NodeSet which is akin to an Array of Nodes. Nokogiri can return the text/contents of a NodeSet or of individual nodes. Perhaps you should search on how to do that?

Comment: Sorry, but both comments don't make sense to me. First of all I've given you an example of the HTML. It's nothing more than the content of that <div></div>. Seconly, it doesn't return a NodeSet. It returns Nokogiri::XML::Element - which is exactly why I'm asking the question.

Comment: `require 'rubygems'` is no more needed since Ruby 1.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting close, but aren't understanding what you're getting back.

Depending on the HTML tag, you could get embedded tags. That's what's happening: You're asking for a single node but it contains additional nodes:

```
puts page.css('div#div_saadi div')[1].to_html
# >> <div style="padding:10px 0">
# >> <span class="t4">content</span>content outside of the span<span class="t2">morecontent</span>morecontent outside of the span</div>
```

`text` works on both a NodeSet and Node. It just grabs the text of whatever you point it at and returns it and doesn't care how many levels it has to descend to do that:

```
result = page.css('div#div_saadi div')[1].text
# => "contentcontent outside of the spanmorecontentmorecontent outside of the span"
```

Instead, you have to iterate over the individual embedded nodes and extract their text:

```
require 'nokogiri'

dummy_content = '<div id="div_saadi"><div><div style="padding:10px 0"><span class="t4">content</span>content outside of the span<span class="t2">morecontent</span>morecontent outside of the span</div></div></div>'
page = Nokogiri::HTML(dummy_content)

result = page.css('div#div_saadi div')[1]
puts result.children.map(&:text)

# >> content
# >> content outside of the span
# >> morecontent
# >> morecontent outside of the span
```

[`children`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node:children) returns all embedded nodes as a NodeSet. Iterating over that returns Nodes, and using `text` on a particular node at that point will return what you want.